# How to preserve the mesh line if I want to remesh the model?

Tags: mesh

I intended to make a boundary line that separates the surface of the cube and that irregular surface made by BSurface.
[image]
I make the boundary line using the knife project.
[image]
However, when I tried to remesh it in Meshlab software, the boundary line disappeared.
[image]
[image]
How can I preserve the boundary line, so that when I want to remesh with any size the boundary line stays there? Or should I separate it into two objects?